# getimagesize() vs finfo_file() for detecting image type?

Tags: php, file-upload

Sometimes images don't have extensions, but are still valid. I have a file upload form and need to detect the filetype to compare it against my whitelist.

I know I can't trust the mime type sent from the browser, so from the research I've done it looks like these are the two options available (they only work after uploading the file):

```
$info      = getimagesize($path);
$imageType = $info['mime'];
```

And

```
$finfo     = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$imageType = finfo_file($finfo, $path);
```

From the testing I've done, it looks like they both work just fine, but I'm wondering if there are any reasons to use one of these methods over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick look at the php source reveals that the `getimagesize()` has support for the following image types:

```
gif, jpeg, png, swf, psd, bmp, tiff, iff, jpc, jp2, jpx, jb2, xbm, ico
```

`finfo_file` has support for a lot more mime types like duskwuff said. On the downside it also does a lot more checks which makes it a little less efficient.

A little test of mine:

```
$startTime = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<50000; $i++)
    getimagesize("test.png");

echo microtime(true) - $startTime;

$startTime = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<50000; $i++) {
    $finfo     = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $imageType = finfo_file($finfo, "test.png");
}

echo '<br>'.(microtime(true) - $startTime);
```

Result:

```
0.85886001586914
3.9046602249146
```

Comment: Do the results of your benchmark change significantly if you move the `finfo_open()` outside the loop?

Comment: "They work by identifying the extension, not parsing the binary file" - huh?! Those functions very well actually look at the binary data; they're at least trying to parse some magic numbers and/or headers.

Answer (score 1):

`getimagesize()` only works on image files recognized by GD. Even if you have everything enabled, that's still only GIF, JPEG, PNG, BMP, and XPM images. `finfo_file()` will give you MIME types for a much wider variety of file types, so it's a much better choice if you expect your code may be used for uploading files that aren't images.