# PHP Laravel 5.4 determine DPI for: jpg, png,psd, tiff, eps and ai

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to determine the DPI for the following files extension:

- jpg
- png
- psd
- tiff
- ai
- eps

For jpg I use the following which is working:

```
$exif = \exif_read_data( $file->getPathname() );

if ( isset( $exif['XResolution'], $exif['YResolution'] ) ) {
    $resolutionX = \explode( '/', $exif['XResolution'] );
    $resolutionY = \explode( '/', $exif['YResolution'] );
    // defaults to 300 to make sure an image is not denied when DPI get not be determined
    $dpiX        = ( $resolutionX[0] ?? 300 ) / ( $resolutionX[1] ?? 1 );
    $dpiY        = ( $resolutionY[0] ?? 300 ) / ( $resolutionY[1] ?? 1 );
}
```

Now how can I do the same for the formats above without installing additional software on my server?

**Update:**
png is working as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with `getimagesize()`

http://php.net/manual/de/function.getimagesize.php

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24853372/1568059 it supports most of the extensions.

> A quick look at the php source reveals that the getimagesize() has
>   support for the following image types:
>
> gif, jpeg, png, swf, psd, bmp, tiff, iff, jpc, jp2, jpx, jb2, xbm, ico
>
> finfo_file has support for a lot more mime types like duskwuff said.
>   On the downside it also does a lot more checks which makes it a little
>   less efficient.